# Issue getting JOIN to work

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I had the following query

```
$stmt2 = $con->prepare("SELECT `id`, `category_id`, `topic_id`, `post_creator`, `post_content`, `post_date` FROM forum_posts WHERE `category_id`=? AND `topic_id`=?");
```

I now am trying to join my users table, so that I can match the `forum_posts.post_creator` to `users.id` and get the username from that.

I am trying this, but the query keeps failing..

```
$stmt2 = $con->prepare("SELECT forum_posts.id, forum_posts.category_id, forum_posts.topic_id, forum_posts.post_creator, forum_posts.post_content, forum_postspost_date FROM forum_posts
        WHERE forum_posts.category_id=? AND forum_posts.topic_id=?
        INNER JOIN users
        ON forum_posts.post_creator = users.id");
       if ( !$stmt2 || $con->error ) {
        // Check Errors for prepare
         die('Stmt2 SELECT prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
        }

            $stmt2->bind_param("ii", $cid, $tid);
            if(!$stmt2->execute()) {
                die('Stmt2 SELECT execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt2->error));
            }
            $stmt2->store_result();
            $stmt2->bind_result($post_id, $post_category_id, $post_topic_id, $post_creator, $post_content, $post_date, $posts_username);
```

I get this error, but cannot figure out what is wrong with that section.

```
Stmt2 SELECT prepare() failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN users ON forum_posts.post_creator = users.id' at line 3
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `inner join` is part of the `from` clause, not part of the `where` clause:

```
SELECT forum_posts.id, forum_posts.category_id, forum_posts.topic_id, forum_posts.post_creator, forum_posts.post_content, forum_postspost_date 
FROM forum_posts
        INNER JOIN users
        ON forum_posts.post_creator = users.id        
WHERE forum_posts.category_id=? AND forum_posts.topic_id=?
```

Comment: Should I leave this part out? `users.username`

Comment: @Paul Can not find this part in your question

Comment: Sorry.. would I do this to get the username? `SELECT forum_posts.id, forum_posts.category_id, forum_posts.topic_id, forum_posts.post_creator, forum_posts.post_content, forum_postspost_date, users.username `

Comment: Yes. You can use that to get `username`

Comment: Worked great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your prepared statement should be like this. `JOIN` should come before `Where`

```
("SELECT forum_posts.id, forum_posts.category_id, forum_posts.topic_id,
         forum_posts.post_creator, forum_posts.post_content, forum_postspost_date 
         FROM forum_posts INNER JOIN users 
                          ON forum_posts.post_creator = users.id
                         WHERE forum_posts.category_id=? AND 
                               forum_posts.topic_id=?"   
    );
```